# Bootstrap 3.3.6: get the same effect as using nav-justified: multiple divs in the same row with same width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to have horizontally aligned elements, that is, in the same row, having the same width? I mean, if I have two `div's`, they will have always 50%, i I have 3 div's they will have 33,3% width. The number of `div's` is not predictable.

I have got that effect using `nav-justified` like here:

```html
            
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" >
  <li ><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
</ul>
```

but... is there any way to achieve the same effect not using `nav-justified` but other classes not related to navbars?

Comment: Why you won't use `nav-justified`?

Comment: @DestinatioN  it is related to navbars... I'm looking for a general way if it exists..

Comment: General way means?? You want to do it by div?

Comment: Taking a look into the Bootstrap CSS result in that `nav-justified` only sets the width to 100% `.nav-justified { width: 100%; }`

Comment: @BlackBird I want to do it _for_ divs, not for navbar